# ANTLR token stream is empty -- why?

Tags: c#, antlr

I'm trying to get a simple calculator up and running in C# using ANTLR.  I have a simple grammar.  The problem is that my token stream is always coming out empty, and I don't understand why.  I've excerpted what I believe is the key code below.  What am I missing?

SimpleCalc.g4:

```
 grammar SimpleCalc;

 options {
 language=CSharp2;
 }

 tokens {
     PLUS,
     MINUS, 
     TIMES,
     DIV
 }

@members {

}

expr    : term ( (PLUS|MINUS) term )* ;
term    : factor ( ( TIMES|DIV ) factor )* ;
factor  : NUMBER ;
DIV : '/';
PLUS : '+';
TIMES: '*';
MINUS: '-';

NUMBER : (DIGIT)+   {System.Console.WriteLine("Found number");  };
WHITESPACE: ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n' | '\u000C' )+   -> skip ;
fragment DIGIT  : '0'..'9';
```

Methods that do the actual work, or try to:

```
class Program {

  public static void Main(string[] args) {
    Run();
  }

  public static void Run() {

    try {
      Console.WriteLine("START");
      RunTestCalculator();
      Console.Write("DONE. Hit RETURN to exit: ");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex);
      Console.Write("Hit RETURN to exit: ");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
  }

  public static void RunTestCalculator() {
    AntlrInputStream inputStream = new AntlrInputStream(@" 9 + 3 ");
    SimpleCalcLexer lex = new SimpleCalcLexer(inputStream);
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lex);
    var t = tokens.Get(0);
    Console.WriteLine("t = " + t.ToString());
    SimpleCalcParser parser = new SimpleCalcParser(tokens);
    try {
      var theExpr = parser.expr();
      Console.WriteLine("found expr " + theExpr.ToString());
    } catch (RecognitionException e) {
      System.Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTION:");
      System.Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
    }
  }
}
```

Console output proves that the above methods are executing, but the tokens don't contain anything:

```
START
ERROR: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: token index 0 out of range 0..-1
   at Antlr4.Runtime.BufferedTokenStream.Get(Int32 i)
   at AntlerTest.Program.RunTestCalculator() in c:\Users\William\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AntlerTest\AntlerTest\Program.cs:line 32
   at AntlerTest.Program.Run() in c:\Users\William\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\
Projects\AntlerTest\AntlerTest\Program.cs:line 19
Hit RETURN to exit:
```

Answer (score 0):

What I was missing was that the token stream remains empty until the expr call.  When I moved the get call after the expr, the token was there:

```
    public static void RunTestCalculator() {
        AntlrInputStream inputStream = new AntlrInputStream(@" 9 + 3 ");
        SimpleCalcLexer lex = new SimpleCalcLexer(inputStream);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lex);
        SimpleCalcParser parser = new SimpleCalcParser(tokens);
        try {
            var theExpr = parser.expr();
            Console.WriteLine("found expr " + theExpr.ToString());
    var t = tokens.Get(0);
    Console.WriteLine("t = " + t.ToString());
        } catch (RecognitionException e) {
            System.Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTION:");
            System.Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
START
Found number
Found number
found expr []
t = [@0,1:1='9',<5>,1:1]
DONE. Hit RETURN to exit:
```